# Consulta dados site da Receita Federal com PHP

Tags: php, libcurl

Realizando uma pesquisa, encontrei alguns exemplos preencher formulários de sites de terceiros e capturar a resposta. A maioria desses exemplos utilizam a biblioteca cURL do PHP.

No site [gigasystem](http://www.gigasystems.com.br/artigo/88/consultar-cnpj-pela-receita-federal-com-php), há um código que mostra como fazer, inclusive usando o captcha.

Eu gostaria de ir um pouco além, fazer "login" no site. Fiz modificações no código, mas sem sucesso. Imagino não estar enviando corretamente as informações, ou seja, não sei exatamente a identificação dos parametros a ser enviado via POST.

Existe alguma forma de descobrir isso?

Comment: Primeiro vc tem que saber quais as infos e nomes dos campos e url para o post a ser enviado etc, ai sim vc podera fazer login com curl isso se o servidor permitir.

Comment: @rafaelphp obrigado pela resposta. Realmente, o mais importante é saber a url para onde o post é enviado, como descobrir? Vendo pelo `form` no html parece que envia para ela mesmo. Não sei se está correto, ou é alguma forma para dificultar...

Answer (score 1):

Olá.
Você pode usar a ferramenta Fiddler para inspecionar as requisições web que são feitas ao realizar cada ação no site desejado. No Fiddler você pode ver os parâmetros da requisições, cookies e outras informações úteis.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @JoelRodrigues. Eu testei o Fiddler, mas não consigo encontrar a parte das requisições. Pode me dar uma "Luz"?

Comment: Veja se este artigo lhe ajuda: http://www.devmedia.com.br/utilitario-fiddler-monitoramento-de-web-services/31274. O autor explica como usar o Fiddler para monitorar serviços.